# Windows App Animations and components in WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I want to develop a desktop application to be used in WIN XP/FORWARD (NET 4). Thats why I was thinking on using WPF to do it.
I know that windows apps can run only on Windows 8, and that is limiting my market. But I found this Microsoft link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738363.aspx
where there is a lot of component examples and animations for windows 8 apps.
What I want to know, is if I can use these components or animations in a WPF app too, as they share the same XAML code.
I have been searching this in google, but there is not much about it. Sadly, WPF seems pretty dead.

Thanks

Comment: `"WPF seems pretty dead."` ummm what, Windows8 store apps only work one Windows8, WPF applications will work on XP,Vista,7,8 and Blue, infact you can do a lot more with WPF then the extremely limited WinRT platform

Comment: What i meant with that is that Microsoft is not releasing new stuff and there are not mamy news about it. And the reason you gave is why i dont develop a windows 8 app. Please stick to the question.

Comment: I think you are confusing Windows8 Metro/Store apps with normal windows applications, they are 2 differnt things, But yes you can use most if not all WinRT xaml animations with WPF, the xaml is pretty much the same, except Windows store apps have more limitations like Triggers etc.

Comment: This is Primarily opinion based. It will get closed. That said, WPF is still the preferred platform for Windows application, because (you said it yourself) WinRT XAML is only supported on Windows 8 and above, and lots of people still have XP / Vista / 7.

Comment: That said, yes, WPF has built in support for animations and there are a lot of awesome WPF samples out there. Check out [this video](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply. I know that they are different things, but as the xaml is the same, i wanted to know if i can use the components and animations that Microsoft offers in that web page for windows 8 apps in wpf. As sa_ddam213 i should, but i tried some code and it was not recognized by the compiler. Its a lame because microsoft is providing a lot of stuff for building windows 8 apps.